# How do you approach debugging something you can't reproduce?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I've made a simple OpenGL application ([link](http://github.com/viclib/3d_multilayer_viewer)). There you can see an image of how it is supposed to look - and how it does look on my computer (OSX):

[image: correct]

Problem is: when my client clones and compiles it on his computer (Ubuntu), this is what he sees:

[wrong http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/wl.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/wl.png)

I'm really puzzled with that. This would be no issue if I could reproduce the bug, but not being able to do so make me clueless on how to even start fixing it. How can I approach this issue?

Comment: Are you sure your client has the latest graphic drivers installed on his machine? Also, is he using an outdated compiler by any chance?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that, but it is supposed to work there. You mean maybe I'm calling some new function? But then, how can I guess?

Comment: Posted an answer - can't really think of an easier way of dealing with the issue.

Comment: I'd log as much as I can and look for differences. Especially used drivers and hardware. THen I'd try to find out if there are any known or similar issues involving the functions I'm using on that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of correcting what I see to be a huge obstacle to getting this code to behave predictably. `gluPerspective (...)` is supposed to be used to setup the projection matrix, you can cram everythng into a single matrix sometimes but it does not make a lot of sense.

```
void GLWidget::paintGL(){
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  /* Original code that does really bad things ... 
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(60.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.01f,650.0f);
  */

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(60.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.01f,650.0f);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(0.0, cam_radius, cam_radius,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
  glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

  ...

}
```

As for debugging something you cannot reproduce, the first step is to think about every state(s) that may produce an effect similar to the one you are (or rather, someone else is) experiencing. This is what I do most of the time on StackOverflow when someone presents a random bit of code and a screenshot. Often the code they initially provide is unhelpful, but the screenshot and description of the problem leads to the right solution; thankfully the comments section allows us to ask for more specific code before committing to an answer.

The first thing that came to my mind when I heard your problem was projection and viewport mapping, which lead me to `qglwidget.cpp` where I discovered some naughty code. It may not necessarily be your entire problem, but it is definitely ***a problem*** that fits all of the criteria.

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I absolutely missed that. I didn't ask for that, but can't not accept this answer after you had that initiative. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I approach this issue?

I suggest using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to create a virtual Ubuntu environment on your machine, so that you can compile and debug the issue yourself.

If it runs as intended on your virtual machine, then the issue is *probably* driver-related on your client's side.

Comment: Sure, but what if I'm not able to reproduce it there (I do think it is probably an OpenGL issue).

Comment: If you're not able to reproduce it there I guess the issue is on your client's side. Make him get the latest drivers or `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Also be aware that it could instead be that *you* have outdated drivers, what the client sees is correct, and your code is wrong but because you developed it with buggy drivers it appears to work. Or both sets of drivers are correct and up to date, but your code accidentally relies on some quantity or behaviour that is actually variable between different implementations of OpenGL, and therefore in principle could even vary between your virtual Ubuntu and your client's Ubuntu (due to different hardware or whatnot).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048079/476681) and use virtualbox, other option is to get the same setup as your client (at least similar hardware, and same OS and installation packages). This way it may prove easier to reproduce and debug.

Sometimes, applications behave differently with different GPUs due to driver problems. Doesn't matter if the drivers are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the weird problems I've had such as this stem from uninitialized data somewhere. Valgrind is a godsend for finding such issues imo. Valkyrie is a nice app to organise its output.

In this specific case I'm going to throw out a wild guess. I've seen this happen before when the window manager sends delayed resize events, or no initial resize event. For example if your code expects to have a resize event sent before the first draw call (or whenever you store the initial window size for setting the viewport and aspect ratio) and the event doesn't happen straight away then you've got the wrong values. My GL framework injects a resize event internally if a real resize event hasn't occurred before entering the main loop (pretty fiddly if you want to ignore the real one when it does finally come along).